# Rails 3 - how to assign the value to nested attributes before calling save in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, attributes

Models associations are

document.rb

```
has_many :sections
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections, :allow_destroy => :true, :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
```

section.rb

```
belongs_to :document
has_many :paragraphs, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :contents :through => :paragraphs
validates :user_id, :presence =>  { :message => "Must be filled" }
```

paragraph.rb

```
attr_accessible :user_id, :section_id, :content_id
belongs_to :section
belongs_to :content
validates :user_id, :section, :content, :presence =>  { :message => "Must be filled" }
```

paragraphs table just like a intermediate table for sections and contents and I want to save records in documents, sections and paragraphs table using single submission.
So I designed form as like

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @document, :validate => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <% f.fields_for :sections do |builder| %> 
   <%= builder.text_field :name %>
   <%= builder.select :content_ids .... {:multiple => true} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

example parameters when submiting the form

```
{"document"=>{"name"=>"sdf", "sections_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"sdf", "description"=>"sdf", "_destroy"=>"0", "content_ids" => ["1", "2"]}}, "commit"=>"Update Document", "id"=>"3"}
```

In additionally, I am updating current_user's id to user_id column of paragraphs table.

update

```
@document = Document.find(params[:id])
@document.attributes = params[:document]
@document.sections.each {|section| 
  section.user_id = current_user.id 
  section.paragraphs.each {|paragraph| paragraph.user_id = current_user.id}
}
if @document.save!
  # success
else
  render :action => 'edit'
end
```

I got "Validation failed: User Must be filled".

Is validation triggered when assigning attributes using object.attributes= as above

How to assign the value to user_id in paragraph object before calling save method

Comment: Validation is triggered on save.

Comment: I hope validation is performed when assigning attributes. after this @document.attributes = params[:document] line error occurred in page with model's validation error message.

Comment: Suggest you use debug with a breakpoint and/or `puts user_id` at that point.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: I use puts after @document.attributes = params[:document] the line that doesn't print. page crashed with validation error message like User must be filled

Answer (score 0):

Might help.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Comment: I also thought this but there are possible that this can be hacked.

Comment: I followed ryan bates tutorial about HABTM to save paragraphs content by passing content_ids in params. Reference: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes. how to include hidden filed here? or Is there any other options?